# The simplest way to input π in text mode (textual)?

Tags: symbols, fontspec, characters, greek

What is the simplest way to input π in text mode if there is only this one greek letter in the whole English text? May be there is one line of code can make it. The following excellent example is suggested by Manuel:

```
%%xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
this is letter π
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is $\pi$ a valid answer? :)

Comment: @masu Nope. In text mode~

Comment: `\usepackage{textgreek}` and `\textpi`. Or may be just take the necessary code for that letter. **EDIT:** you use `fontspec`? Then just load a font with the letter π, and write π in text mode.

Comment: @EdenHarder but what do you mean by `text mode` if I told you to use foobar package and then `\tpi` to get a text pi, would it matter if internally the package did `\newcommand\tpi{$\pi$}` ? `$` is used internally all over the place, most minipages, parboxes, tabular etc are all inside `$`..`$`  That said, if you want a textual pi there are of course Greek text fonts yo could use (but if you want pi for the circle $\pi$ is probably the most natural encoding)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that's the point I was trying to make (but you giftwrapped it in a much nicer way). `\pi` is a math mode command, `$\pi$` can be used in text mode...

Comment: @EdenHarder Would this “π” represent the number?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! Here `text mode` means plain text without `math mode`. If we use `math mode`, then we should do some other work to keep the style of the whole text identical.  Textual pi is just I want, but I don't know which font contents it. Thanks all!

Comment: @Manuel  Textual pi is just what I want, but I don't know which font contents it.

Comment: Expand your question, because it's still not clear what you really want. By the way, almost every font contents pi (did you try with any?).

Comment: Sorry, but you have not given enough information for the question to make sense. You are using some font for your English text but you have not said which. If that font has a pi then you could use the pi from the same font, but unless you are using xetex then almost certainly the font will not have a pi, so you need to choose a pi from another font that matches your text. If you are using another font then the font choice is the thing, whether internally TeX uses math mode or text mode is irrelevant. We can't suggest a greek font that matches your latin font if you don't  give any information

Comment: In your minimal example you are not using `fontspec` with any font. E.g., add `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}` to your preamble.

Comment: @Manuel How to know which font contains π? or which font contains the most characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leave the hard work to `textgreek`. If you need the letter to work also in math mode, add a suitable definition with `\newunicodechar`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{textgreek}

% use these if you also want π to work in math mode
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{π}{\ifmmode\pi\else\textpi\fi}

\begin{document}
This is π as a letter in text mode and
we can use it also in math: $e^{πi}+1=0$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and `fontspec` it is another matter. Your example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
this is letter π
\end{document}
```

works out of the box, because Linux Libertine *does* have Greek letters.

[image]

Just by way of example, let's suppose the main font doesn't have Greek letters; one can then use a workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}{Futura} % just for a very different font

\newunicodechar{π}{{\greekfont π}}    \begin{document}

this is letter π
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can have a look at the `ucharclasses` package in case you have several characters missing from the main font.

Comment: Thanks so much! There may be some other ways, so let's wait for some time. Thanks again.

Comment: Egreg, one of the tags is `fontspec`. Which will ease the problem partially (apart from using XeTeX), but I think we still don't know what @EdenHarder wants.

Comment: @Manuel I want to see what is the simplest way to solve this question. In the beginning, I think _Then just load a font with the letter π, and write π in text mode_ may be the one but I DO not know what's the proper font (maybe with extended characters?). Now, I want to see what is the simplest way at last.

Comment: @EdenHarder Perhaps you could make clearer what environment you're in: are you using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with `fontspec`? If so, what's the document preamble?

Comment: @EdenHarder But IF you are in XeLaTeX, with `fontspec`, you can write `this is letter π` and get no errors. That's why we don't know what your problem is and what are you really asking. As egreg said, add more info (a minimal working example would be great).